Not able to codesign .exe files in mac M1 (MacOS Sonoma) using osslsigncode
I have been codesigning .exe files using macOS and osslsigncode for many years without major issues.
I have an Extended Validation (EV) CodeSigning Certificate correctly installed on a PKCS#11 token.
The osslsigncode tool has stopped working since I did a brew update. I suspect is when it updated OpenSSL.
I see it reads the certificate correctly, but it hangs after message ‘Engine “pkcs11” set’.
There's no output error at all, it just hangs and -verbose method is already set.
I'm using Mac M1 with macOS Sonoma 14.0 installed.
I'm using libs installed with brew:
libp11 0.4.12
osslsigncode 2.8, using:
OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024)
libcurl/8.1.2 SecureTransport (LibreSSL/3.3.6) zlib/1.2.12 nghttp2/1.55.1
I have tried updating osslsigncode using Github latest code and rebuilding it.
https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode
Also using brew install osslsigncode. I get the same exact issue with both different ways, even in 2 different machines.
The osslsigncode command I'm trying to execute, which worked for a couple of years without issues is:
$dir"/osslsigncode sign -verbose -pkcs11engine /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libp11/0.4.12/lib/engines-3/pkcs11.dylib -pkcs11module /usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib -h sha256 -pass 'pass' -in "$1" -out "${1}".EEK -key 8e9a398de48403837f38ee1d2403f3ac -certs "${dir}/cert2025.pem" -t 'http://timestamp.globalsign.com/?signature=sha2'
Is anybody that can replicate this issue with osslsigncode using latest libs in Mac M1 and Sonoma?
Do you have any ideas how to troubleshoot this?
Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

Did you report the issue to the osslsigncode project?
